# InDesign Script to create URLs

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

Is there a script to use within InDesign so it finds a URL within textframes and it turns it into a hyperlink?

As I am aware, to create a hyperlink within InDesign requires you to right click and manually create the hyperlink.

Answer (score 4):

It is a built-in feature. Open the *Hyperlinks* panel and select *"Convert URLs to Hyperlinks..."* in the panel menu:

[image]

Comment: As i am inputting content from an XML document, after import it does not recognise the href within an xml tag to form a hyperlink. For example, there could be a <tag href="www.google.com"> click here </tag> and it will not recognise it

Comment: Ok, not sure I can help then. But have you tried to just export an "Interactive PDF" (not "Print PDF")? Most times the links just work without being defined as hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't normally need a script for this as InDesign can detect URL's by default. If a PDF is the end goal, then you simply need to check 'Hyperlinks' in the PDF export panel and the resulting PDF will have links included for all URL's.

[image]

Comment: As i am inputting content from an XML document, after import it does not recognise the href within an xml tag to form a hyperlink. For example, there could be a <tag href="www.google.com"> click here </tag> and it will not recognise it

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Selecting the Include Hyperlinks option in the PDF export window has no effect unless you actually define Hyperlinks in your document. If not, Acrobat tries to find valid URLs automatically if you have the 'Create links from URLs' option checked in Acrobat preferences—but that's a feature of Acrobat, not InDesign. Other PDF readers may or may not do the same thing.